# Please Solve the Error in Magento

Tags: magento

Error in file:

> /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/local/AccessShop/ThemeOptions/data/themeoptions_setup/data-install-1.0.5.php` - A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.

Trace:

> #0 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
>       #1 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-install', '', '1.0.5')
>       #2 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installData('1.0.5')
>       #3 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
>       #4 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(362): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
>       #5 /home/mystyletag/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #6 /home/mystyletag/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>       #7 {main}

Error log record number: 1170042499126

Answer (score 1):

As per the error it shows static blocks are already created in database with same identifier. So you can delete the particular `identifier` static block from db and run the theme installation again.